# Error consuming webservices in C# .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have to consume a third party Webservice built in Axis2 from .Net

So I'm trying to add a service reference using the webservice wsdl address(`https://service/Services.wsdl`) and I get the following error :

```
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
- The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
- There was an error downloading https://service/Services.xsd. 
...etc
```

The last error (error downloading .xsd) is probably what's causing me this issue. It is because VS2010 tries to download it at this address : `https://service/Services.xsd`

But in fact it lays here : `https://service/GoodServices.xsd`

**EDIT**

How can I tell VS2010 to take the xsd from the correct link above instead of the wrong resolution resulting from the incorrect wsdl ?

Comment: take a look at the wsdl itself. The "wrong" URL should be mentioned somewhere in the document or one of the referred documents. This is usually a problem of the service provider.

Comment: Yes it is somewhere in the wsdl and i found how to resolve it myself : https://preprodservices.crif-online.ch/CrifSS/CrifSoapServiceV1?xsd=crif-soap-service_v1.0.xsd but now how can i tell VS2010 to check there instead of where it checks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a long way around, but works for me.

- Download the wsdl from the browse and save it as xml
- Include this xml in your project in Visual Studio
- open the wsdl xml file in the visual studio.
- modify the schema location ("schemalocation" attribute) at line 6 to the correct xsd location, i.e, `https://preprodservices.crif-online.ch/CrifSS/CrifSoapServiceV1?xsd=crif-soap-service_v1.0.xsd`
- Save the file
- Now right click on the project and select "Add Service Reference..."
- In the Address: box, enter the physical path (`C:\test\project....`) of the downloaded/Modified wsdl.
- Hit Go

Comment: It's exactly what I've done in the meantime ^^ Thanks a lot for your answer !